# Strange lag when playing COD: Ghosts on PS4

Tags: ps4

The lag doesn't appear to be network related, it's too consistent, it's almost like it goes in slow motion for about 1-2 seconds. It doesn't appear to be when anything particular is happening on screen either, it happens mabe 5-6 times in a period of a couple hours. My setup has everything plugged into the receiver via HDMI and them from the receiver to the TV, a Samsung 50" LCD, 1080p, 60Hz. Would having the PS4 hooked to the TV then HDMI to the receiver make a difference?

Comment: Is it only with COD: Ghosts or also with other games?

Comment: well, I just bought the system last week and it is currently the only game I own.

Comment: Try to plug your ps4 directly in your TV. It is possible the receiver makes it "laggy".

Comment: Come to think of it, the PS4 menu is sometimes a bit jumpy too.

Comment: You tried to connect the PS4 to the TV directly? And if you did, did it work?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to plug your PS4 Directly in your TV. So remove the receiver. It is possible that the receiver is interupting the signal.